# Confusion about Levi-Civita determinant identity

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, determinant, index-notation

From the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Determinants) on the Levi-Civita symbol, they write the following equation
$$
\sum_{i_1,i_2,...}\epsilon_{i_1...i_n}a_{i_1j_1}...a_{i_n j_n}=\det(\mathbf{A})\epsilon_{j_1...j_n},
$$
which I assume can be written in Einstein notation as
$$
\epsilon^{i_1...i_n}a_{i_1j_1}...a_{i_n j_n}=\det(\mathbf{A})\epsilon_{j_1...j_n}.
$$
I now assume that $a_{ij}=g_{ij}$ is the metric tensor. I can use it to lower every index on the Levi-Civita symbol on the left hand side
$$
\epsilon_{j_1...j_n}=\det(\mathbf{A})\epsilon_{j_1...j_n}.
$$
But for this equation to be correct, I must conclude that $\det(\mathbf{A})=1$. This seems very incorrect to me, but I cannot fathom, where the error lies in my calculations. Any help clarifying this issue is much appreciated!

Comment: The $a_{(...)}$ are meant to be taken as the components of $\mathbf A$, so if you set $a_{ij}=g_{ij}$ you must set $\mathbf A=\mathbf g$, in which case $\det \mathbf A=\det\mathbf g=1$, so there are no problems.

Comment: It's important to note that lack of consistency with respect to indices on the wikipedia page. Generally, only the determinant of an endomorphism makes sense, but here endomorphisms are written with respect to their metric dependent representation $a_{ij}=g(Ae_i,e_j)$ and not the independent representation $a^{j}_i=\langle A e_i, e^j\rangle $ so the matrix $g_{ij}$ represents the identity (which must have determinant $1$)

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter I am a bit out of my depth here, but something I fail to see is why $g_{ij}$ should be the identity because it is written in its metric dependent representation.

Comment: To extract the components of an endomorphism with respect to the metric $g$, one writes $a_{ij}=g(Ae_i, e_j)$ (we find the result of projecting the image of the $e_i$ basis vector onto the $e_j$ basis vector. Plugging in $A=\mathrm{id}$ we have $a_{ij}=g(\mathrm{id} e_i,e_j)=g(e_i,e_j)$ which is the definition of the components of the metric tensor, $g_{ij}$.